# Get Extras (variables) out of an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

I want to get three `variables` off another `class` in my java (android) projects `main activity`. Therefore I put them in a `bundle` and got it into an `Intent`. The variables are from an `Object` I created in a third class which is the following:

```
public class Transaction {
    private float value;
    private int transaction_Date;
    private String description;

public Transaction(float value, int transaction_Date, String description){
    super();
    this.value = value;
    this.transaction_Date = transaction_Date;
    this.description = description;
}

public float getValue(){
    return value;
}
public int getTransaction_Date(){
    return transaction_Date;
}
public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}


public void setValue(float value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public void setTransaction_Date(int transaction_Date) {
    this.transaction_Date = transaction_Date;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

Here is my attempt to get the data into the mentioned `Intent`:

```
public class AddMoneyTransaction extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button addDepositButton;
EditText depositInput, depositInputDate, depositInputNote;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_money_transaction);

    //setup the Button and EditText

    addDepositButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addDepositButton);
    depositInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depositInput);
    depositInputDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depositInputDate);
    depositInputNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depositInputNote);

    //get the onClickListener

    addDepositButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent depositIntent = new Intent(AddMoneyTransaction.this, AssetsOverview.class);
    Transaction deposit = new Transaction(100, 16, "random comment");
    deposit.setValue(Float.parseFloat(depositInput.getText().toString()));
    deposit.setTransaction_Date(Integer.parseInt(depositInputDate.getText().toString()));
    deposit.setDescription(depositInputNote.getText().toString());

    Bundle depositBundle = new Bundle();
    depositBundle.putFloat("value", Float.parseFloat(depositInput.getText().toString()));
    depositBundle.putInt("date", Integer.parseInt(depositInputDate.getText().toString()));
    depositBundle.putString("description", depositInputNote.getText().toString());

    depositIntent.putExtras(depositBundle);
    startActivity(depositIntent);
}
```

And this (of course) does not work:

```
//populated transaction list

protected void populateTransactionList() {

    Intent depositIntent = getIntent();
    Transaction deposit = (Transaction) getIntent().getExtras();
}
```

So how am I able to get my three variables out of my `Intent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to pass the custom object through the intent is to implement the Parcelable interface similar to the Transaction class given below.

**Make Transaction class parcelable like the given below snippet**

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class `Transaction` implements Parcelable {
    private float value;
    private int transaction_Date;
    private String description;

    public Transaction(float value, int transaction_Date, String description) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
        this.transaction_Date = transaction_Date;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public float getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getTransaction_Date() {
        return transaction_Date;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }


    public void setValue(float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setTransaction_Date(int transaction_Date) {
        this.transaction_Date = transaction_Date;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeFloat(this.value);
        dest.writeInt(this.transaction_Date);
        dest.writeString(this.description);
    }

    protected Transaction(Parcel in) {
        this.value = in.readFloat();
        this.transaction_Date = in.readInt();
        this.description = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Transaction> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Transaction>() {
        @Override
        public Transaction createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Transaction(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Transaction[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Transaction[size];
        }
    };
}
```

**Put the Parcelable object into the intent as given below**

```
        public class AddMoneyTransaction extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        Button addDepositButton;
        EditText depositInput, depositInputDate, depositInputNote;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_money_transaction);

            //setup the Button and EditText

            addDepositButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addDepositButton);
            depositInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depositInput);
            depositInputDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depositInputDate);
            depositInputNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depositInputNote);

            //get the onClickListener
            addDepositButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent depositIntent = new Intent(AddMoneyTransaction.this, AssetsOverview.class);
           Transaction deposit = new Transaction(100, 16, "random comment");
           deposit.setValue(Float.parseFloat(depositInput.getText().toString()));
           deposit.setTransaction_Date(
Integer.parseInt(depositInputDate.getText().toString()));
           deposit.setDescription(depositInputNote.getText().toString());
           depositIntent.putExtra("data",deposit);
           startActivity(depositIntent);
        }
```

**And receive the intent as given below**

```
//populated transaction list

protected void populateTransactionList() {

    Intent depositIntent = getIntent();
    Transaction deposit = depositIntent.getParcelableExtra("data");
}
```

Comment: Okay so my app stopped crashing. Now how am I able to access the data in the bundle after I recieved it in my main Activity? (I need a variable to work with (display the data in the main Activity))

Comment: I have mentioned it in the above answer about how to receive data of all your custom object in another activity.

Comment: Added the variable of various text view  that you want to pass. Let me know If I am missing something?

Comment: Sorry if my explenation was a little bad. I got the Intent recieved in my Main Activity and now want to have the data that I sent over this Intent in my bundle to be a variable again (in my Main Activity) so I can work with the three variables of my 2nd Activity in my Main Activity just as I would if they were created in my Main Activity. [I need a variabe named Value, one named Description and one named Date with each the value of the corresponding variable in my 2nd Activity (which i just sent over)]

Comment: In the populateTransactionList function, you have the access of the object that you have passed from the previous activity. If you want to access it globally, assign it to global variable and use the getter accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
Transaction deposit = (Transaction) getIntent().getExtras();
```

The extras are a `Bundle`. You know this, because you have:

```
depositIntent.putExtras(depositBundle);
```

to fill in those extras.

Since you called `putFloat("value", ...)`,  `putInt("date", ...)`, and `putString("description", ...)` on that `Bundle`, you would use the associated getters to retrieve the values from the extras based on those keys. That could be done by:

- Calling `getFloatExtra()`, `getIntExtra()`, and `getStringExtra()` directly on the `Intent` returned by `getIntent()`, or
- Get the `Bundle` of extras via `getIntent().getExtras()`, then call `getFloat()`, `getInt()`, and `getString()` on the `Bundle`

A `Transaction` cannot go into the extras, as you cannot put arbitrary Java objects into the extras. You could make `Transaction` [implement `Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), in which case you could put it directly into the extras.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.